# jquery does not change margin property.of a div

Tags: jquery, margin

This is my first question on JQuery.

I have 3 Buttons. All are horizontally aligned like:

`1st: Button`                                      `2nd: Button`                                      `3rd: Button`

I have 1 div named `popup`.

If I click on button 1 the div should be shown like :

`1st: Button`                                      `2nd: Button`                                      `3rd: Button`

`div: popup`

If i click on 2nd button then it should be :

`1st: Button`                                      `2nd: Button`                                      `3rd: Button`

`div: popup`

For 3rd button :

`1st: Button`                                      `2nd: Button`                                      `3rd: Button`

`div: popup`

Using JQuery, I have selected the element. I calculate the margin-left of the button and store that in variable. I make the div invisible. Then I apply that margin to the div. And finally I make it visible. Here is the code.

```
<script>
    $('img').click(function () {
        var clickedImageMargin = $(this).css('margin-left');
        alert(clickedImageMargin);
        $('#popup').hide();
        $('#popup').css({ 'margin-left': clickedImageMargin + 100 });
        $('#popup').show();
    });
</script>
```

But div does not change its position. What might be the problem?

Comment: Can you please provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: What do you mean by jsFiddle?

Comment: Go to http://jsfiddle.net and create a page containing your html,css, javascript and then share it with us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var clickedImageMargin = $(this).position().left;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$(this).css('margin-left')` returns a string, which is e.g. '200px'
If you add 100 to that, string concatenation will be used, so you're setting a value of '200px100', which is invalid.

Comment: ya thats true. Thanks for pointing that mistake. Now I got it using parseInt()